# Transaction list to basket data

Tags: r, list, transactional

I have a table like

```
ID    Productpurchased   Year
1A          Abc          2011
1A          Abc          2011       
1A          xyz          2011
1A          Abc          2012
2A          bcd          2013
2A          Abc          2013
```

Output required format

```
ID       Purchase basket     Year     Abc-count  xyz-count  bcd-count    
1A       (Abc,xyz)           2011      2           1          0
1A       (Abc)               2012      1           0          0
2A       (bcd , Abc)         2013      1           0          1
```

Comment: Your original question with the data as text, not images, was better.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(ID, Year) %>% summarise(basket = toString(unique(Productpurchased)), Abc = sum(Productpurchased == 'Abc'), bcd = sum(Productpurchased == 'bcd'), xyz = sum(Productpurchased == 'xyz'))`

Comment: or more programmatically, `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(ID, Year) %>% summarise(basket = toString(unique(Productpurchased)), tab = list(table(Productpurchased)), vars = map(tab, names)) %>% unnest() %>% spread(vars, tab)`

Comment: or go backwards from counting to the basket: `library(tidyverse); df %>% count(ID, Year, Productpurchased) %>% spread(Productpurchased, n, fill = 0L) %>% mutate(basket = apply(.[3:5] > 0, 1, function(x){toString(names(.)[3:5][x])}))`

Comment: Good to know these approaches. thanks  @alistaire!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this easily with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID' , 'Year', `paste` the `unique` elements of 'Productpurchased' and assign (`:=`) it to create 'Purchase_basket' column, then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' specifying the `fun.aggregate` as `length`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, Purchase_basket := toString(unique(Productpurchased)),.(ID, Year)],
       ID + Year + Purchase_basket ~paste0(Productpurchased, ".count"), length)
#    ID Year Purchase_basket Abc.count bcd.count xyz.count
#1: 1A 2011        Abc, xyz         2         0         1
#2: 1A 2012             Abc         1         0         0
#3: 2A 2013        bcd, Abc         1         1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same logic as data.table but using dplyr.

```
df_2 <- read.table(text = 'ID    Productpurchased   Year
1A          Abc          2011
1A          Abc          2011       
1A          xyz          2011
1A          Abc          2012
2A          bcd          2013
2A          Abc          2013',
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



df_2 %>% group_by( ID, Year) %>%  
  mutate(Abc_count=grepl("Abc", Productpurchased), 
         bcd_count=grepl("bcd", Productpurchased),
         xyz_count=grepl("xyz", Productpurchased)) %>% 
  summarise(Productpurchased = paste("(", paste(unique(Productpurchased), collapse = ","),")", sep=""),
            Abc_count=sum(Abc_count), 
            bcd_count=sum(bcd_count),
            xyz_count=sum(xyz_count))
```